# Date updated on each click

Tags: javascript, jquery, date, event-handling, click

In my app i want to navigate through certain dates. On first click i get the date i need, but on second click it stays the same.

```
var getDate = function() {

  var d = new Date();
  var month = d.getMonth()+1;
  var day = d.getDate();
  var yesterday = d.getDate()-1;
  var tomorrow = d.getDate()+1;

  var output = d.getFullYear() + '/' +
      ((''+month).length<2 ? '0' : '') + month + '/' +
      ((''+day).length<2 ? '0' : '') + day;



  $('#yesterday, #tomorrow').click(function () {
      if (this.id === 'yesterday') {
        var output = d.getFullYear() + '/' +
            ((''+month).length<2 ? '0' : '') + month + '/' +
            ((''+day).length<2 ? '0' : '') + yesterday;
        $("#today_date").text(output);
      }
      else if (this.id === 'tomorrow') {
         var output = d.getFullYear() + '/' +
             ((''+month).length<2 ? '0' : '') + month + '/' +
             ((''+day).length<2 ? '0' : '') + tomorrow;
         $("#today_date").text(output);
      }
  });
  $("#today_date").text(output);

};
```

[jsfiddle example here](http://jsfiddle.net/7LXPq/800/) http://jsfiddle.net/7LXPq/800/

Comment: You want to keep incrementing/decrementing dates on each click?

Comment: Yes on each click to go +1 or -1 day

Comment: Then you are doing it the wrong way, and also you are decrementing the  days only which will go to <0 or >31.

Comment: Check your updated fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/coder_raaaz/7LXPq/811/), i have not minimized it for your understanding.

Answer (score 0):

Every time you click on `yesterday` and `tomorrow` you need to update your current `d` date. Otherwise you are always stuck in today date.

Trying to keep as much as your original code you can refactor it like this:

```
var getDate = function() {

  var d = new Date();

  var formatDate = function () {
    var month = d.getMonth()+1;
    var day = d.getDate();
    var output = d.getFullYear() + '/' +
       ((''+month).length<2 ? '0' : '') + month + '/' +
       ((''+day).length<2 ? '0' : '') + day;

    return output;
  };

  $('#yesterday, #tomorrow').click(function () {
    d = new Date(d);
    if (this.id === 'yesterday') {
      d.setDate(d.getDate() - 1);
    }
    else if (this.id === 'tomorrow') {
      d.setDate(d.getDate() + 1);
    }
    $("#today_date").text(formatDate());
  });
  $("#today_date").text(formatDate());
};
```

See [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/7LXPq/809/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code:

```
var getDate = function() {

   var d = new Date();

   var output = d.getFullYear() + '/' +
    (d.getMonth() + 1 < 10 ? '0' : '') + (d.getMonth()+1) + '/' +
    (d.getDate() < 10 ? '0' : '') + d.getDate();

    $('#yesterday, #tomorrow').click(function () {
        if (this.id === 'yesterday') {
            d.setDate(d.getDate()-1);
            var output = d.getFullYear() + '/' +
            (d.getMonth() + 1 < 10 ? '0' : '') + (d.getMonth()+1) + '/' +
            (d.getDate() < 10 ? '0' : '') + d.getDate();
            $("#today_date").text(output);
        }
        else if (this.id === 'tomorrow') {
            d.setDate(d.getDate()+1);
            var output = d.getFullYear() + '/' +
            (d.getMonth() + 1 < 10 ? '0' : '') + (d.getMonth()+1) + '/' +
            (d.getDate() < 10 ? '0' : '') + d.getDate();
            $("#today_date").text(output);
        }
    });
    $("#today_date").text(output);

};
```

if you need the current date to be kept, you can just make a copy of the `d` variable before using it